# hs.htmlExpand to the open popup on image click

Tags: javascript, highslide

I would like, when the user click on image in the open popup, the content will changed with url in iframe (not close/open, but crossfade)

I have a gallery with hs.transitions = ['expand', 'crossfade'].

Next construction will close old popup window and open new one (and break the slideshow), but i want the same effect (crossfade), like a user click next image.

```
hs.allowMultipleInstances = false;
hs.Expander.prototype.onImageClick = function()
{
    return hs.htmlExpand(null, { objectType: 'iframe', src: 'url' });
};
```

How to make it?

Sample - http://jsfiddle.net/xCnfE/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t crossfade from an image to a HTML popup if the HTML popup isn’t part of the gallery. Instead you can create a regular iframe that covers the image with jQuery and show this iframe only when clicking the image (`onImageClick`). Please see http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/B7sDG/

```
hs.Expander.prototype.onImageClick = function (sender) {
    $('<iframe src="'+this.custom.url+'" frameborder="0"></iframe>').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '0',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        background: '#fff',
        zIndex: 20
    }).appendTo(sender.wrapper);
    return false;
};
```

The `url` is passed to the iframe `src` using [hs.custom](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.Expander.prototype.custom) in the `onclick`:

```
<a href="large-image.jpg" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this, galleryOptions, {url: 'http://highslide.com/'})">
    <img src="thumbnail.jpg" alt="Caption Text" />
</a>
```